# merge sort in java not working please review my code and suggest me the required corrections

Tags: java, sorting, merge

this is my java code for merge sort algorithm.I have used merge(int l[],int r[],int a[]) method to merge the sorted array using divide and conquer algo.the mergesort(int a[]) is used to partition the complete arrar into two halves recursively until it returns after the base condition is satisfied.

The correct output is not coming.There is some mistake in the algo.
Please let me the know the exact problem.Thanks in advance.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;    
        class sort
        {
            void merge(int l[],int r[],int a[])
            {
                int l1=l.length;
                int l2=r.length;
                int i=0;
                int j=0;
                int k=0;
                while(i<l1&&j<l2)
                {
                    if(l[i]<=r[j])
                    {
                        a[k]=l[i];
                        k++;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a[k]=r[j];
                        k++;
                        j++;
                    }
                    while(i<l1)
                    {
                        a[k]=l[i];
                        i++;
                        k++;
                    }
                    while(j<l2)
                    {
                        a[k]=r[j];
                        j++;
                        k++;
                    }
                }
            }
            void mergesort(int a[])
            {
                if(a.length<2)
                    return;
                int mid=a.length/2;
                int left[]=new int[mid];
                int right[]=new int[a.length-mid];
                for(int i=0;i<mid;i++)
                {
                    left[i]=a[i];
                }
                for(int i=mid;i<a.length;i++)
                {
                    right[i-mid]=a[i];
                }
                mergesort(left);
                mergesort(right);
                merge(left,right,a);
            }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int n;
                n = sc.nextInt();
                int a[] = new int[n];
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    a[i] = sc.nextInt();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                sort obj = new sort();
                obj.mergesort(a);
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
                    System.out.print(a[i]+" ");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The correct output is not coming." That's a very imprecise definition of what's wrong. What's your input? What's the output? What's the expected output? Have you used a debugger to step through the code? What happened, and at what point did it not behave as you expected it to? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: You need to let us know the exact problem and then we can let you know what the solution is.

Comment: The problem is solved thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sort {
    void merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r, int left, int right) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        while (i < left && j < right) {
            if (l[i] <= r[j]) {
                a[k++] = l[i++];
            } else {
                a[k++] = r[j++];
            }
        }
        while (i < left) {
            a[k++] = l[i++];
        }
        while (j < right) {
            a[k++] = r[j++];
        }
    }

    void mergesort(int a[], int n) {
        if (n < 2)
            return;
        int mid = n / 2;
        int left[] = new int[mid];
        int right[] = new int[n - mid];
        for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            left[i] = a[i];
        }
        for (int i = mid; i < n; i++) {
            right[i - mid] = a[i];
        }
        mergesort(left, mid);
        mergesort(right, n - mid);
        merge(a, left, right, mid, n - mid);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of intgers: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter an intger: ");
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        Sort obj = new Sort();
        obj.mergesort(a,n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

    }
}
```

A sample run:

```
Enter the number of intgers: 10
Enter an intger: 34
Enter an intger: 2
Enter an intger: -7
Enter an intger: 78
Enter an intger: 45
Enter an intger: 4
Enter an intger: 12
Enter an intger: -10
Enter an intger: 6
Enter an intger: 60
34 2 -7 78 45 4 12 -10 6 60 
-10 -7 2 4 6 12 34 45 60 78
```

Please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your merge method does not handle tails of the arrays to be merged. Once one finish scanning one of the arrays you must continue iterating over the second array until it is also finished.

Consider the following implementation taken from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/):

```
/* Merge the temp arrays back into arr[l..r]*/
i = 0; // Initial index of first subarray 
j = 0; // Initial index of second subarray 
k = l; // Initial index of merged subarray 
while (i < n1 && j < n2) 
{ 
    if (L[i] <= R[j]) 
    { 
        arr[k] = L[i]; 
        i++; 
    } 
    else
    { 
        arr[k] = R[j]; 
        j++; 
    } 
    k++; 
} 

/* Copy the remaining elements of L[], if there 
   are any */
while (i < n1) 
{ 
    arr[k] = L[i]; 
    i++; 
    k++; 
} 

/* Copy the remaining elements of R[], if there 
   are any */
while (j < n2) 
{ 
    arr[k] = R[j]; 
    j++; 
    k++; 
}
```

Your code lacks the bottom 2 loops that handle the tails of either array.